# converting individual characters in string to uppercase

Tags: python-3.x

my code

```
name='helloworld' 
i=0  
while(i<len(name)):
    name[i].upper()
    i=i+2
    print(i)
print(name)
```

want the output as `'AnThRoPoMoRpHiSm'`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate your string and capitalize one of every 2 letters, then join the result:

```
name='anthropomorphism'
''.join([s if i%2 else s.upper() for i,s in enumerate(name)])
```

This returns:

```
'AnThRoPoMoRpHiSm'
```

Comment: Thank you! got it